# sql query run successfully in mysql, but not in yii migration

Tags: sql, yii, migration

I'm a newbie to yii and have found a problem when executing a migration file. Below is the migration code (sorry the field name are in Indonesian:

```
public function safeUp()
{
    $this->execute("
        ALTER TABLE `t_retur_pembelian` ALTER `kode_pembelian` DROP DEFAULT;
        ALTER TABLE `t_retur_pembelian` CHANGE COLUMN `kode_pembelian` `kode_post_pembelian` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL AFTER `kode`, DROP FOREIGN KEY `FK_T_PEMBELIAN_T_RETUR_PEMBELIAN`, ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_t_retur_pembelian_t_post_pembelian` FOREIGN KEY (`kode_post_pembelian`) REFERENCES `t_post_pembelian` (`kode`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;
    ");
}

public function safeDown()
{
    return false;
}
```

Every time I tried to execute this migration, it is always failed with errors:

```
...Exception: CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000] [1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE `t_retur_pembelian` CHANGE COLUMN `kode_pembelian` `kode_post_pembel' at line 2. The SQL statement executed was: ALTER TABLE `t_retur_pembelian` ALTER `kode_pembelian` DROP DEFAULT;
```

But when I execute those two lines of sql query in mysql, it run successfully. What is wrong with the migration file? Can anybody help me? I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

> ```
> $this->execute("ALTER TABLE `t_retur_pembelian` ALTER `kode_pembelian` DROP DEFAULT");
> $this->renameColumn('t_retur_pembelian', 'kode_pembelian', 'kode_post_pembelian VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL AFTER `kode`');
> $this->dropForeignKey('FK_T_PEMBELIAN_T_RETUR_PEMBELIAN', 't_retur_pembelian');
> $this->addForeignKey('FK_t_retur_pembelian_t_post_pembelian', 't_retur_pembelian', 'kode_post_pembelian', 't_post_pembelian', 'kode', 'NO ACTION', 'NO ACTION');
> ```

I don't know what wrong with your sql, maybe in one execution must do one action, but my code must work. Don't forget `return true;`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But unfortunately, There is error in the second execute.
...Exception: CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1025] Error on rename of '.\sunrise\#sql-a40_3f' to '.\sunrise\t_retur_pembelian' (errno: 150). The SQL statement executed was: ALTER TABLE `t_retur_pembelian` CHANGE COLUMN `kode_pembelian` `kode_post_pembelian` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL AFTER `kode` (D:\xampp\htdocs\sunrise\yii\framework\db\CDbCommand.php:338)

Comment: hi CreatoR, sorry but, your code actually works, just need to exchange second execute and dropForeignKey. Thank you!

Comment: Good! I'm make some modification if interesting how you can change column name in yii